# NotImplementedException System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObjectInternal()

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have never seen this error, it was thrown by .net code itself:

```
System.NotImplementedException: O método ou a operação não está implementada.
   em System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   em System.Windows.Clipboard.GetDataObjectInternal()
   em System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorCopyPaste.OnQueryStatusPaste(Object target, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnCanExecute(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnCanExecute(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.UIElement.OnCanExecuteThunk(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
   em System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   em System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   em System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   em System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   em System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecuteWrapper(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CanExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, Boolean& continueRouting)
   em System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecute(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, Boolean& continueRouting)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.TransferEvent(IInputElement newSource, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnCanExecute(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.UIElement.OnCanExecuteThunk(Object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object target)
   em System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   em System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   em System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   em System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   em System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecuteWrapper(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CanExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, Boolean& continueRouting)
   em System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.CriticalCanExecute(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean trusted, Boolean& continueRouting)
   em MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CanExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource commandSource)
   em System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.UpdateCanExecute()
   em System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteChangedEventManager.HandlerSink.OnCanExecuteChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   em System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList.DeliverEvent(Listener& listener, Object sender, EventArgs args, Type managerType)
   em System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args, Type managerType)
   em System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.RequerySuggestedEventManager.OnRequerySuggested(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   em System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.RaiseRequerySuggested(Object obj)
   em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   em System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

It happened in my WPF application, when I right-clicked a `TextBox`. When right-clicking `TextBox` it usually shows CTRL+C CTRL+V commands.

**EDIT**

I **don't have** *handlers for copy, paste, cut*, however I've created my own context menu because I added another menu item. And I did it with a `Behavior`

```
internal class VariableSelectorBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

                AssociatedObject.ContextMenu = CreateContextMenu();
        }

        private ContextMenu CreateContextMenu()
        {
            var viewModel = new VariableSelectorViewModel(IoC.Get<IVariableList>(), IsRequired, DataType);
            viewModel.VariableSelected += VariableSelected;

            var variableMenu = new MenuItem { Header = "Variables" };
            variableMenu.DataContext = viewModel;
            variableMenu.AddHandler(MenuItem.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(VariableMenuItemClick));
            variableMenu.SetBinding(MenuItem.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("Items"));
            variableMenu.SetBinding(MenuItem.VisibilityProperty, new Binding("HasItems")
            {
                Source = variableMenu,
                Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
            });

            var separator = new Separator();
            separator.SetBinding(MenuItem.VisibilityProperty, new Binding("HasItems")
            {
                Source = variableMenu,
                Converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
            });

            var menu = new ContextMenu();
            menu.Items.Add(variableMenu);
            menu.Items.Add(separator);
            menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Command = ApplicationCommands.Cut });
            menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Command = ApplicationCommands.Copy });
            menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem { Command = ApplicationCommands.Paste });

            return menu;
        }
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce this at all, several times I tried. Does anyone have a clue of what happened here?

Comment: Did you auto generate the handlers and didn't add your own code? By default auto generated method stubs throw NotImplementedExceptions. Also it would be helpful to see your actual code...

Comment: without code we cannot help

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this wasn't something in my code. I've added what I think is the relevant part. And I was wrong,  I don't have handlers for copy,paste,cut